# Volume of a hollow cone using triple integral?

Tags: calculus, volume

I want to directly find out the volume of a hollow cylinder instead of subtracting the smaller volume from the bigger volume...Considering both the outer cone and inner cone to have the same cone angle and the same longitudinal axis , Help me with this problem!!

Comment: Are you talking about a cone or a cylinder? And do you have any reason to believe that there is a nice and elegant way to do it which is not just subtracting one volume from the other?

Comment: Arthur, I know there is no method more simpler than just subtracting the volumes..I am talking about cones.. i was wondering if its possible to triple integrate volume of a hollow cone? is it not possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to integrate, however, the way I would do it the area integral of the outer minus the inner coordinate (i.e., the area integral of the cone width), which is equivalent to subtracting the volumes if you re-organize the terms.

Comment: Ertxiem Hey! Can you write it down for me.. Because both areas have different heights so I am unable to write an accurate equation of what you just said! Much appreciated!